# running commands from cloud-builders-community/sonarqube/

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-container-registry, cloudbuild.yaml

```
gcloud builds submit . --config=cloudbuild.yaml
Creating temporary tarball archive of 6 file(s) totalling 3.2 KiB before compression.
Uploading tarball of [.] to [gs://training_cloudbuild/source/1670817617.242895-f55df2adc5e04b5ca65f2ed1a6a12fe4.tgz]
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) 403 Could not upload file [/tmp/tmprwqmw411/file.tgz] to [training_cloudbuild/source/1670817617.242895-f55df2adc5e04b5ca65f2ed1a6a12fe4.tgz]: Access denied.
```

running commands from cloud-builders-community/sonarqube/ in the instance and getting this error .Need help how to run sonar scanner in cloud build .Need to use sonarqube while running the code in cloud build.

Answer (score 0):

From [Troubleshooting build errors documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/troubleshooting#4xx_client_errors)

> **4xx client errors**
> This group of errors indicates that the build
> request is not successful presumably by fault of the user sending the
> request. Some examples of 4xx client errors are:

```
**Error**: 404 : Requested entity was not found
**Error**: 404 : Trigger not found
**Error**: 400 : Failed Precondition
**Error**: 403 : Permission denied
```

Error message:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) 403 Could not upload file [/tmp/tmprwqmw411/file.tgz] to [training_cloudbuild/source/1670817617.242895-f55df2adc5e04b5ca65f2ed1a6a12fe4.tgz]: Access denied.
```

The error stats, the Service Account does not have access to `[gs://training_cloudbuild/]`

Try adding below permission to build Service Account:

```
storage.objects.create
storage.objects.get
storage.objects.list
```